# How to click on span text using selenium webdriver python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

Not able to click the button "continue" through selenium web driver, which is inside the span tag.

```
<span style="align-items: center; align-self: center; flex: 1 1 auto; margin: 0px 4px; max-width: 100%; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">
    <span>Continue</span>
</span>
```

Comment: <span style="align-items: center; align-self: center; flex: 1 1 auto; margin: 0px 4px; max-width: 100%; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;"><span>Continue</span></span>

Comment: Which error are you getting? Can you share a link? Show us the code you have so far. Provide more information about your issue. It is impossible to help you with current input

Comment: without error stack trace we can not do anything.

Comment: @cruisepandey, In short, I just want to run the login process for JIRA. If you can help me out in doing this will be appreciated.

Comment: JIRA is domain specific. Do you have any global URI?

Comment: @cruisepandey please find the URL "https://id.atlassian.com"

Comment: @GuruprasadPadukone : That's what , I can not run this URL in my local machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically you don't click the *span text* but you click on the `<span>` with text as **Continue** and you can use the following solution:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span/span[contains(.,'Continue')]").click()
```

Comment: Tanx. It worked for me. But after running this  command I wanted to run these lines "password=browser.find_element_by_id('password')
password.send_keys('******')". BUt it was throwing the error "selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible". Please help me out in doing the login for Jira. "https://id.atlassian.com"

Comment: @GuruprasadPadukone Glad to be able to help you !!! Can you raise a new question with your new requirement please?